# Newline character is not interpreted correctly in MimeMessage?

Tags: java, mime-types, mime, mime-message

```
StringBuffer emailMessage = new StringBuffer("Dear Scott");
emailMessage.append("\r\n");
emailMessage.append("Sending mail over internet");
```

So here is my formatted content when i inspect in debugger

```
Dear Scott,
Sending mail over internet
```

But when i receive it in thunderbird, i receive  complete message in one line like below. Somehow newline character
 is not interpreted correctly when sending the content as html

```
 Dear Scott,Sending mail over internet
```

here is how i am sending the message as html

```
 MimeMessage msg = null;
 msg = new MimeMessage(mailSession);
 msg.setText(body, CHARSET_UTF_8, "html");
```

If i simply send the text as  msg.setText(body, CHARSET_UTF_8) then i see the message in right format i.e "Sending mail over internet" in seen in
next line. **I am not getting why new line character is not interpreted correctly when sending the text as html?**

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Because you're sending an HTML email, you have to use `<br />` instead of `\r\n`, just like a *classic* HTML document (e.g. a `.html` file). When you use  `\r\n`, the rendered content won't print a new line, but the source code of the mail will (and vice versa).

Answer (score 11):

HTML does not interpret newline characters. When you set the content type to "html", use "<br/>" instead of "\r\n":

```
StringBuffer emailMessage = new StringBuffer("Dear Scott");
emailMessage.append("<br/>");
emailMessage.append("Sending mail over internet");
```